# How to store a folder with spaces inside a batch script using the SET /P command and call the stored variable while using the POWERSHELL -Command

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-line-arguments, multilingual

I have a batch script that adds or removes folder paths to Windows Defender's exclusion list.

I have issues when using folder paths with spaces only.

I have tried escaping the spaced path using double quotes multiple ways.

```
Escape Method1: \"%FDIR%\"

Escape Method2: `"%FDIR%`"

Escape Method3: `""%FDIR%`""
```

The basic flow of the script is

1. Prompt user for input of folder path and store it in the FDIR var
2. The first POWERSHELL command will add the path stored in the FDIR var
3. The last POWERSHELL command at the bottom will show the current
   exclusion list so the user can see what they are dealing with
   and to verify if the first POWERSHELL command worked (it will show up if successful)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
COLOR 0A

:----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

:: USING SET /P COMMAND I STORE THIS PATH EXACTLY...
:: SPACES AND ALL WITH NO SURROUNDING QUOTES IN FDIR VARIABLE: C:\Program Files\ASRock Utility
SET /P "FDIR=ENTER A FOLDER PATH: "

:----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

:: EXECUTE POWERSHELL COMMAND USING THE CHOSEN PATH STORED IN THE FDIR VARIABLE
POWERSHELL -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "Start-Process POWERSHELL -ArgumentList '-WindowStyle Hidden -Command Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath \"%FDIR%\"' -Verb RunAs"

:----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

:: DISPLAY THE CURRENT FOLDER EXCLUSIONS IN POWERSHELL WINDOW
POWERSHELL -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "Start-Process POWERSHELL -ArgumentList '-WindowStyle Maximized -Command Write-Host "Current Excluded Folders"; Write-Host; Get-MpPreference | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ExclusionPath; Write-Host; Read-Host "Press Enter To Exit"; EXIT' -Verb RunAs"
```

Comment: It would also be much better, if you did not allow your end user to insert doublequotes, as part of their input, _(you should remove them before dealing with the variable)_. I would also suggest that you would also need to escape any singlequote/apostrope in their input with a backtick. The main thing is that regardless of your reported issue, asking for the path as input, requires pre-validation of that input. Are you sure that the `ExclusionPath` array requires its paths to be quoted? My first instrinct would be that those may only be necessary should your paths include the array delimiter.

Comment: As a follow up / confirmation of my first instinct comment above, take a look at the `ExclusionPath` property output from `Get-MpPreference` shown in [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/1591375). The output shows the array as comma separated, and includes whitespace and an apostrophe, but those paths are not doublequoted.